# Using razor pages in ASP.NET Core minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, minimal-apis

I am using [Minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) in ASP.NET Core. I need to return a Razor page. Is there any way to do this?

I have added

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
app.MapRazorPages();
```

in `program.cs` file. And I have `index.cshtml` file under the root `Page` folder, but it doesn't work:

```
public async static Task<RedirectToPageResult> Get()
{
    return new RedirectToPageResult("index");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean   `return razor page` ? Do you want  to add two more calls - `AddRazorPages()` and `MapRazorPages()` - for supporting Razor Pages ? If so,
you can  add Pages folder under the project root. And add a new Razor Page named Index.cshtml to it.

Comment: @QingGuo thanks for reply . question updated please check

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the  below steps:

In `Program.cs` add two more calls - `AddRazorPages()` and `MapRazorPages()` - for supporting Razor pages :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

Add `Pages` folder under the project root. And add a new Razor page named `Index.cshtml` to it, like this:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Update**

Create a `Student.cshtml` razor page then try:

```
 public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> OnGetAsync()
 {
     return new RedirectToPageResult("Student");
 }
```

Result:

[image]